# Small power series "approximating" a Dirac

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, power-series

Does there exist a (sequence of) power series $\sum_{i\geq 0} a_{n,i} x^i$ that is $1$ at $0$ and $0$ at integers from $1$ to $n$, and such that $\sum_{i\geq 0} \vert a_{n,i}\vert n^i=O(n^p)$ for some real $p>0$?

Comment: What is the quantification over $n$?  At first $n$ seems to be a fixed number (the largest integer on which you require the power series to vanish), but then you treat it as a variable (a certain power series in $n$ is polynomial in $n$).

Comment: Assuming that $n$ is fixed, why not just the standard Lagrange interpolation $\frac1{n!}\prod_{i = 1}^n (i - x)$?

Comment: The phrasing is confusing indeed, sorry. Here $n$ is variable, i'm really asking about a sequence of power series (with more and more values prescribed) such that the asymptotic behavior of the second sum is polynomial in $n$. The Lagrange example gives an exponential growth (or more)

Comment: I still don't understand; maybe more explicit indexing would help.  Is it correct that you want the $n$th power series $\sum a_{n i}x^i$ to be $1$ at $0$ and to vanish for $x \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$?  Is your condition then that $\sum \lvert a_{n i}\rvert n^i$ is polynomial in $n$?  And does "polynomial in $n$" mean *bounded* by a polynomial, or actually *equal* to a polynomial?

Comment: The Lagrange polynomial from @LSpice 's second comment is essentially inevitable: if $\sum |a_{nj}|n^j≲n^N$, then the coefficients with $j>N$ will be ridiculously small, so the polynomial $\sum_{j=0}^N a_{nj}x^j$ must solve an interpolation problem extremely close to the original one

Comment: @Lspice: yes, this is exactly what I'm asking. ChristianRemling: yes, I now suspect such power series might not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such functions do not exist. Let us call them $f_n$. Your conditions imply that
$f_n(0)=1, \; f(k)=0$ for $ 1\leq k\leq n-1$ and $M(n,f_n)\leq Cn^p$, where $M(r,f):=\max\{|f(z)|:|z|=r\}$. Now [Jensen's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) says that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\frac{n}{k}\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|f_n(ne^{i\theta})|d\theta.$$
The RHS is at most $p\log n+\log C$, while the LHS is
$$n\log n-\log n!\sim n$$
by Stirling's formula. So we obtain a contradiction.